# Mixing solvents of different polarity

Tags: solvents, polarity

Suppose a non-polar solid is dissolved in ethanol. Water is added to the solution. Will the solid separate, if it isn't soluble in water?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75100/is-it-possible-for-a-compound-to-be-soluble-in-a-mixture-of-solvents-but-not-the https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32025/how-do-i-predict-the-solubility-of-a-compound-in-a-mixture-of-water-and-an-organ

Comment: Sorry, I worded it wrong. Will edit.

Comment: Yes. How much water you have to add before seeing separation will depend on the specific system (solute, conc., T).